# Image in LibreOffice Write failed to load

Tags: libreoffice

how to fix if image shows read error to load in libreOffce Write

Comment: version of both Ubuntu and LibreOffice? Size and nature of image??

Comment: This should be an issue with LibreOffice. Ask the question on https://ask.libreoffice.org/

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha questions about working with LibreOffice are **on topic** here.

Answer (score 1):

LibreOffice Writer shows the read error message when it tried to fetch an image from its source online, but failed to retrieve it, possibly because the server timed out or blocked the request to download the image. In order to remove the error message, visit the webpage where the image is located and save the missing image to your hard drive. Then insert the saved image into your document manually with *Insert* -> *Image*.

After the image is inserted in the document, you can right-click the image and select *Anchor* -> any of the 4 anchor options to anchor the image at its position in the document. Embedding an image in a document and anchoring an image are two separate things. Anchoring an image just locks the position of the image at a fixed place in the document.

[image: anchor image]